# Unable to login while using hawtio as standalone app

Tags: hawtio

I am unable to login if I am using hawtio embedded in a jetty server(dropwizard). I can't see any option to disable login option too. It would be better if there is method to add users also.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration guide has details how to disable login, by settign a jvm system property

- http://hawt.io/configuration/index.html

Adding and removing users is not part of hawtio. You use whatever management tool you use for that. Some servers like jetty allows to define users in a configuration file which you can manually configure.

Though usually people may have an existing infrastrucuture for user management, such as LDAP. So you configure jetty to use that, which hawtio can use by setting up JAAS.

But you really need to provide more details in your questions before we can help you.